# Regex for digits and a plus sign

Tags: javascript, regex

The conditions of the regex are as follows:

Starts with either digits or a '+' sign and ends with digits.

This is going to be used to validate a certain type of number. What I got so far is:

```
/^\d*|\+\d*$/
```

This regex seems to match any string though. How would a regex that matches my conditions look like?

The regex will be used in a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^(?:[+\d].*\d|\d)$
```

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[+\d]` Matches a plus symbol or a digit.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `\d` Matches a digit.
- `|` OR
- `\d` A single digit.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Use this if you want to match also a line which has a single plus or digit.

```
^[+\d](?:.*\d)?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is close to what I was looking for. However it does not match a single digit (I might have not been clear on that).

Comment: This appears to match expressions where the + symbol is not at the start, e.g. 123+456.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use anchors `^` and `$` on both sides of your regex and make first part `+` or digit) optional.

You can use this regex:

```
^([+\d].*)?\d$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qO1oN1/1)

Comment: I have anchors on both sides, just like your regex. PS: This doesn't match my conditions, in fact it doesn't match any digits. Is there a typo?

Comment: This appears to match expressions where the + symbol is not at the start, e.g. 123+456.

Comment: Yes that is due to OP's requirement that `Starts with either digits or a '+' sign and ends with digits`. It doesn't say anything for the characters in the middle.

Comment: I interpreted that as meaning the string can be either all digits, or all digits with a + at the start. Maybe it's more subjective than I thought.

Comment: Even the accepted answer allows `+` in the middle